# Flutter: form shifts when validation is false

Tags: forms, flutter

i'm building a UI for a login form with validation.

Here is the page:

[image]

I'm overall very pleased with the look of the page and it works fine. There is just one exception: when the user inputs invalid parameters in the fields (one or more) the form shifts and the button responsable for the password visibility is not centered anymore.
I searched online and they suggest to wrap it in an Expanded widget, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Here's a image, that shows the problem:

[image]

Here is the code:

```js
import 'package:email_validator/email_validator.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:client/providers/cloudfirestore_provider.dart';

import 'package:client/screens/forgotpass_screen.dart';
import 'package:client/screens/register_screen.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final email = TextEditingController();
  final password = TextEditingController();

  bool _obscureText = true;
  IconData iconData = Icons.visibility;

  var isLoading = false;

  final focus = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Builder(
        builder: (ctx) => SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                width: double.infinity,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
              ),
              Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                            MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top) *
                        0.4,
                  ),
                  ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
                    child: Container(
                      child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.jpg'),
                      height: 150,
                      width: 150,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                        MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top) *
                    0.6,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30, horizontal: 60),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "Hi, there!",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.grey[900]),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 210,
                      child: Form(
                        key: _formKey,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: TextFormField(
                                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                                onFieldSubmitted: (v) {
                                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focus);
                                },
                                controller: email,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Email"),
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                                validator: (value) {
                                  if (EmailValidator.validate(value)) {
                                    return null;
                                  }
                                  return "Please enter a valid email";
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Stack(
                                children: [
                                  TextFormField(
                                    focusNode: focus,

                                    controller: password,
                                    decoration:
                                        InputDecoration(labelText: "Password"),
                                    obscureText:
                                        _obscureText, // create little eye to show password
                                    validator: (value) {
                                      if (value.length < 6) {
                                        return 'Minimum 6 characters';
                                      }
                                      return null;
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  IconButton(
                                      icon: Icon(iconData),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        setState(
                                          () {
                                            _obscureText = !_obscureText;
                                            if (iconData == Icons.visibility) {
                                              iconData = Icons.visibility_off;
                                            } else {
                                              iconData = Icons.visibility;
                                            }
                                          },
                                        );
                                      })
                                ],
                                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 20,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              width: 200,
                              height: 50,
                              child: FlatButton(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                                ),
                                color: Colors.deepOrange,
                                textColor: Colors.white,
                                onPressed: () async {
                                  Scaffold.of(ctx).hideCurrentSnackBar();
                                  setState(() {
                                    isLoading = true;
                                  });
                                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                    login(email, password) async {
                                      try {
                                        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                                        await FirebaseAuth.instance
                                            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                                                email: email.text,
                                                password: password.text);
                                        if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser
                                                .emailVerified ==
                                            false)
                                          Scaffold.of(ctx).showSnackBar(
                                            SnackBar(
                                              content: Text(
                                                  "Please verify your email."),
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        else
                                          Scaffold.of(ctx).showSnackBar(
                                            SnackBar(
                                              content:
                                                  Text("Logging you in ..."),
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        setState(() {
                                          isLoading = false;
                                        });
                                      } catch (e) {
                                        print(e.toString());
                                        if (e.toString() ==
                                            "[firebase_auth/wrong-password] The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.") {
                                          Scaffold.of(ctx)
                                              .hideCurrentSnackBar();
                                          Scaffold.of(ctx).showSnackBar(
                                            SnackBar(
                                              content: Text(
                                                  "The password is incorrect."),
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        } else if (e.toString() ==
                                            "[firebase_auth/user-not-found] There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.") {
                                          Scaffold.of(ctx)
                                              .hideCurrentSnackBar();
                                          Scaffold.of(ctx).showSnackBar(
                                            SnackBar(
                                              content: Text(
                                                  "There is no email adress connected to this account."),
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        } else if (e.toString() ==
                                            "[firebase_auth/too-many-requests] We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity. Try again later.") {
                                          Scaffold.of(ctx)
                                              .hideCurrentSnackBar();
                                          Scaffold.of(ctx).showSnackBar(
                                            SnackBar(
                                              content: Text(
                                                  "We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity. Try again later."),
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        } else {
                                          Scaffold.of(ctx)
                                              .hideCurrentSnackBar();
                                          Scaffold.of(ctx).showSnackBar(
                                            SnackBar(
                                              content: Text(
                                                  "Pls check your internet connection and try again."),
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        }
                                        setState(() {
                                          isLoading = false;
                                        });
                                      }
                                    }

                                    await login(email, password).whenComplete(
                                        () => CloudFirestoreProvider().addUser(
                                              email.text,
                                              password.text,
                                            ));
                                  } else
                                    setState(() {
                                      isLoading = false;
                                    });
                                },
                                child: (isLoading)
                                    ? CircularProgressIndicator(
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                      )
                                    : Text('Submit',
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            FlatButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => ForgotPassScreen(),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                "Forgot Password ?",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrange),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
                            FlatButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => RegisterScreen(),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                "Register",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrange),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT:

I tried swapping the Stack method for the suffixIcon suggested. And it works except for the position of the Icon that is off-centred.

[image]

Here's the updated code:

```js
Expanded(
                              child: TextFormField(
                                focusNode: focus,

                                controller: password,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: "Password",
                                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                        color: Colors.grey[900],
                                        icon: Icon(iconData),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          setState(
                                            () {
                                              _obscureText = !_obscureText;
                                              if (iconData ==
                                                  Icons.visibility) {
                                                iconData = Icons.visibility_off;
                                              } else {
                                                iconData = Icons.visibility;
                                              }
                                            },
                                          );
                                        })),
                                obscureText:
                                    _obscureText, // create little eye to show password
                                validator: (value) {
                                  if (value.length < 6) {
                                    return 'Minimum 6 characters';
                                  }
                                  return null;
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your icon in the sufficient property of the input Decoration on your password text field.

```
inputDecoration(suffixIcon: IconButton())
```

Comment: I tried it , but like this is always slightly off-centred.

Comment: I have a published app that does the same thing.  Unfortunately, because of the way errors are done as part of the TextField widget, this will always happen.  It basically resizes the input part of the TextField to allow room for the error.  You can try setting Text widgets underneath the TextFields that only display when there is an error.